# After debian upgrade, npm is not working

Tags: debian, alias, npm

I upgraded from Debian 9 to 10, and Emacs from 25 to 26.1. Then, npm was NOT working and missing but node was there.

Then, re-installed npm using:

```
$ sudo apt-get install npm
  npm succesfully installed

$ npm -v
  alias?
  node package manager RET

$ which npm
  npm is an alias, defined as "node package manager"

$ npm --version
$

$ type -a npm 

npm is /usr/bin/npm
```

But, **npm is not working...**

How to solve it?

Can someone help, please?

Comment: Could you please edit your post and add the actual output of these commands?

Comment: Kusalananda: Done

Comment: @tom_kp No, sorry, I meant the _actual_ output, not descriptions of what happened. Also add the output of `type -a npm`.

Comment: @Kusalananda: `$ type -a npm`           

`npm is /usr/bin/npm`

Comment: Reinstall `npm`: `sudo apt purge --autoremove npm` then `sudo apt install npm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall `npm`:

```
sudo apt purge --autoremove npm
sudo apt install npm
```